# How to remove duplicates of a column on a data frame which is characters in R?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to remove all duplicated in a certain column that are identical characters. For example in the flights data frame below:

```
flights %>%
filter(dep_delay > 10, !is.na(origin)) %>%
distinct(flights$orgin)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Column `flights$orgin` is of unsupported type NULL
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'orgin'.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I am just trying to get rid of any duplicate origins pretty much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it the typo of 'orgin'?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
flights %>%
  filter(dep_delay > 10, !is.na(origin)) %>%
  distinct(origin)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Despite correcting the typo, it still does not work for me.